# how to use values from selectinput SHINY

Tags: r

I need some help with shiny package.
I try to use the values put into a Selectinput but it's does not work properly.

Here my code:

```
inputPanel(
  selectInput("ticker1", label = "tickers:",
              choices = c('OR.PA', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MT', 'BNP.PA', 'BTC-USD'), selected = 'AAPL')
)

inputPanel(
  selectInput("ticker2", label = "tickers:",
              choices = c('OR.PA', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MT', 'BNP.PA', 'BTC-USD'), selected = 'AAPL')
)

inputPanel(
  selectInput("ticker3", label = "tickers:",
              choices = c('OR.PA', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MT', 'BNP.PA', 'BTC-USD'), selected = 'AAPL')
)

actionButton("go", "Submit")
```

```
tickers <- reactive({
  c(input$ticker1, input$ticker2, input$ticker3)
  })

prices <- renderTable({
  tq_get(tickers,
                      from = '2022-01-01',
                      to = '2022-05-30',
                      get = 'stock.prices')
  })
```

After choosing the 3 tickers, I click on button submit to display the table which will contain all stock prices data downloaded from Yahoo direcly with library tidyquant (function tq_get() but it does not work....
Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: Try using `tickers()` in `tq_get`.

Comment: Hi, there is a no change with tickers() :-(

Comment: @rouroux in addition to using `tickers()`...without a complete example it is difficult to tell...but you probably want `tableOutput("prices")` somewhere in your `ui`, as well as include `output$prices <- renderTable({...})` in your `server` function...

Comment: @Ben Thank you very much its works with a tableOutput("prices") in my ui + tickers() into the tq_get() function. In addition, I put a output$prices <- renderTable({
  tq_get(tickers(),
                      from = '2022-01-01',
                      to = '2022-05-30',
                      get = 'stock.prices')
  })